# Why foreign key is invalid in eXtremeDB?

Tags: time-series, embedded-database

I installed eXtremeDB emebeded on my Ubuntu 20.04, and tried following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE coops (id1 INT NOT NULL, name string NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id1));
CREATE TABLE factories (id  INT NOT NULL, name string NOT NULL, coop INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (coop) REFERENCES coops (id1));
```

I found it available to insert rows intn `factories` while `coops` contains nothing. Like below:

```
// no rows in coops    
INSERT INTO factories values (1, 'a', 1);
```

And `Metatable` reveals that no column had referenced.

Why does my foreign key failed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get when you try to execute your queries. Also show the result/status message for each successful executed query.

Comment: @Progman Hi, I've added insert command, but I actually get no erro message. The commands just succeeded...